# Certificate Pinning and Corporate MITM

Tags: tls, hsts, certificate-pinning

What I still don't understand about certificate pinning is - why am I still able to access Google apps through a corporate MITM? I know that I have the root cert for my corporation installed on my PC, but shouldn't Google throw an error when its sites are signed by a cert (my corporation's cert) that does not match one of the pinned certs on Google's servers? Maybe I'm misunderstanding how pinning works.

Comment: What browser are you doing that with?

Comment: Chrome. With my current understanding of pinning, I assumed that with corporate MITM (I work in security consulting and am testing out a MITM solution that does malware analysis), I would not be able to access Google Apps because the pinned certificates do not match the cert used for the MITM.

Answer (score 9):

With browsers that have certificate pinning, user-installed root CAs are normally exempted from pinning requirements; if the certificate received doesn't match the pinned certificate or key but *is* signed by a custom-added CA, the browser doesn't complain. This is done to support the exact scenario here, as well as the scenario where a user decides to MitM themselves (to, for instance, inspect all of their own network traffic). [Source](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2011/05/04/pinning.html) (the blogger in question, Adam Langley, works on the Chrome network stack and Google's HTTPS infrastructure).